# SLAM not working in m-explore-ros2 package

Tags: ros2, slam

I am using a TurtleBot3 and I want to use the m-explore-ros2 package to introduce autonomy to my robot. I included the package in my launch file and got the MarkedArray display in Rviz, however, I  am not able to navigate the map and only get the basic Rviz map as shown below. Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Is it a slam_toolbox problem?

I looked into rqt and I am not getting any action data.